# Heroku error in logs: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver

Tags: java, heroku

I am a total newbiew to heroku deployments.
I have a java application pushed to Heroku using only the heroku toolbelt . I have put the .war file in my app.

the servelet is in turn talking to derby db.

Now when i try and access the same from my client the heroku logs show an error:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver`

when i use the same .war file in glassfish server locally it works fine.

Not sure about if i need to seperately install derby.jar to heruko? , if so how do i add it using toolbelt.

or is there something i am missing here

Answer (score 0):

The Glassfish server you are using locally is providing the derby JAR file for you app. This makes it an unmanaged external dependency (which is bad).

In order to run your application on Heroku, you would need to include the derby driver in your Maven dependencies. Probably something like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
  <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
  <version>10.11.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

However, keep in mind that the Heroku filesystem is emphemeral, and Derby won't persist. You could try the [free PostgreSQL database that Heroku provides](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql).